# List Recursion in Ocaml

Tags: recursion, ocaml

This is what I want to achive, to return to a list with values that are below the given value with **recursion**:

```
# list_below 3 [7; 1; 0; 3];;
   - : int list = [1; 0]
# list_below 1 [-7; 1; 0; 3];;
   - : int list = [-7; 0]
# list_below 9.0 [4.2; 3.6; 5.0; 12.8];;
   - : float list = [4.2; 3.6; 5.0]
```

Here is what I wrote so far, and it does not appear to return anything.

```
let rec list_below thresh lst = 
 if List.hd lst > thresh then [] else
  List.hd lst :: list_below thresh (List.tl lst);;
;;
```

Could you show me what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2):

The problem should be what Jeffrey has pointed out for you.

Your questions says you want to implement `list_below`, but your code shows `list_above`. I'll stick to `list_below` here.

**Recursive functions** in Ocaml can be made quite intuitively if you use [pattern matching](https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/data_types_and_matching.html). For example, the below code should work :

```
let rec list_below thresh lst =
  match lst with
  | [] -> []
  | hd :: tl -> if hd < thresh then hd :: (list_below thresh tl)
            else list_below thresh tl;;
```

Comment: By the way, if you just change your `if List.hd lst > thresh then []` to `if List.hd lst > thresh then list_below thresh (List.tl lst)` it would raise error for not taking in consideration the empty list.

Comment: I'm not sure if this would be considered as folding. There's no accumulator.

But if you do want the code to be likely to the code in your question, you could add an if predicament to check for empty list before comparing the value of List.hd to avoid raising the error stated in the above comment.

Answer (score 0):

If the first value is above the threshhold your code always returns an empty list. That can't be right. It is inconsistent with your first example, for one thing.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `List.filter`. Since you want to get a list of values that are less than the supplied value, then filter should do what you want.

Here's the documentation for filter:

```
val filter : ('a -> bool) -> 'a list -> 'a list

filter p l returns all the elements of the list l that satisfy the predicate p. The order of the elements in the input list is preserved.
```

What you need is to provide a predicate p. A predicate is a function that takes an element and returns a boolean. Filter will take this predicate and apply to each value in the list. If the predicate returns true for that element, the element will be added to the resulting list.

So in your case, `list_below` should be

```
let list_below thresh lst =
    List.filter (fun elem -> elem < thresh) lst
```

More more operations on list, check out this [chapter](https://v1.realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/lists-and-patterns.html) in Real World OCaml.

Comment: he emphasized that he needed to to implement the function with recursion. I'm guessing `filter` won't do the trick.