# For statement without integers

Tags: list, for-loop, recursion, match, ocaml

For learning reasons, I would like to use for loops in OCaml instead of recursion.

I've researched a bit and applied one example of (https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/camlp4_3.10/foreach_tutorial.html):

```
let a_list = ["hello"; "world"] in
for s in a_list do
  print_endline s
done
```

This makes sense. However, when I look at it (on Visual Studio, for instance), it tells me that 's' is an int variable. Therefore, I cannot do stuff like (where 'a', 'b',... are variables of any type):

```
let a_list = [a;b;c...] in
for s in a_list do
  match s with
    ...
done
```

Is there not a way to use the for statement like in Python? I mean, to use 's in list' and that s's type will be its type and not 'int'?

There is something I do not see there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no foreach in OCaml. Recursion is the idiomatic style, or if you really want to avoid recursion, you can use `while` loop. For loop only iterate on integers.

You might be confused on the nature of the tutorial that you are linking: this is a tutorial for implementing a (old style) syntax extension for OCaml, and not a tutorial on using `for` loop in OCaml.

Comment: I see.. Thank you very much! No trouble with recursions, I just want to use loops in a naturally functional language. I will try with `while` and post it here the same answer with it (if it results interesting). Thanks again!

Comment: No interest on using `while`, just use natural list recursion, like in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52267786/list-recursion-in-ocaml

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, but the idiomatic approach would be to use `List.iter`.

```
let a_list = ["hello"; "world"] in
List.iter print_endline a_list
```